# Example of classification dataset where SVM with linear kernel performs well

Tags: classification, dataset, svm

I'm looking for a dataset (preferably with a story, at any rate a real dataset) 
where a SVM with a linear kernel performs well...in other words i'm looking for 
a dataset where the class boundary is likely to be linear. Ideally, there should 
 be between 10-20 continuous variables and not too many discrete ones....

It's not really important to me how many classes there are (as long as it's 
a classification problem). Also, it can't be the iris dataset.

Any proposals?

P.S.: @modo: i don't think this is a question about  obtaining a particular dataset: 
it's more that i have not read svm/machine learning papers since i was a master student so i'm not familiar with some comon good examples...i'm just sure they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/URL+Reputation ?
It seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Attribute Characteristics: Integer, Real

Comment: sorry I had misread this,